# Structuring a meteor app with models

Tags: meteor

I'm building a meteor app which works out fine. But coming from Backbone, I miss the structure. Especially the models. In the unofficial FAQ they state where to put your models, but I can't find any examples.

What do Meteor models look like? Are BB models a good option?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at: https://github.com/Exygy/minimongoid

Answer (score 0):

I've create an atmosphere package for meteor models. Here is the link https://github.com/EmmN/meteor-mini-models .
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Meteor Astronomy https://github.com/jagi/meteor-astronomy